# Onsen Themes not applying

Tags: css, cordova, onsen-ui

Using onsenui, I customized the components using Onsen UI's theme webapp.  As far as I know all I have to do is replace the "onsen-css-components.css" file with the one I downloaded and the theme should change, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I've compared the original css file with the one that I downloaded and the changes are there, but when I run my app somehow the changes are not applied.

Answer (score 2):

That should be enough if your app is including `onsen-css-components.css`. It is possible that, if you started from a minimum template, it is including `onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css` or any other instead, so make sure you include the right one. If you are using [Monaca](https://monaca.io) you can check `www/components/monaca-onsenui/loader.css` to see which one your app is using.

You can also override some specific css styles by writing [modifiers](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#OverridingCSSstyles).